# How to configure ZeroClipboard for pdf generation?

Tags: datatables, zeroclipboard

I am using Datatable Tools to export some table to PDF but I am getting error while exporting the data. The error says

`This instance of ZeroClipboard is not configured for PDF export. Please use the PDF export version.`

Anyone knows how I can configure ZeroClipboard.js so I can get PDF?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you have it working and its displayed properly on the DataTable. I had the same problem recently and the fix was fairly easy, all I had to do was change the location of the swf file to the PDF one. Below is an example.

`"sDom": '<"clear">lfrtipT',
  "oTableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "/js/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/TableTools-2.0.0/media/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
 }`

Normally the default import is just "copy_cvs_xls.swf". The other file should be in the same location, check it out and import it instead.

Comment: Yes friend you are right! I had done this earlier but I really appreciate you share your experience. Actually it was due to relative path (which was incorrect) I have used absolute path instead and everything works fine. Thanks again